# Why is Gradle runner missing in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Why is the runner under Gradle missing and how to add it?
I do not have this option as in the image.

[image]

IDE logs:

------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,199 [     78]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/0t/qw0pb2s54jvd7yh2t342dqj83_zh2s/T/intellij-shell-env.tmp' 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,425 [    304]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-193.6494.35, 11 Feb 2020 06:35) 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,433 [    312]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.15.1, x86_64) 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,433 [    312]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,434 [    313]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,435 [    314]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf -Xverify:none -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/dinicolae/java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/dinicolae/java_error_in_idea.hprof -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Users/dinicolae/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.3/idea.vmoptions -Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents -Didea.executable=idea -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2019.3 
2020-03-06 14:10:16,435 [    314]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=UTF-8 file=UTF-8 
2020-03-06 14:10:17,076 [    955]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (10 vars) 
2020-03-06 14:10:17,125 [   1004]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
2020-03-06 14:10:17,262 [   1141]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 1046 ms 
2020-03-06 14:10:19,233 [   3112]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Gradle Extension" misses optional descriptor profiler-java-gradle.xml 
2020-03-06 14:10:19,868 [   3747]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 4; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@477fa4e6[Running, parallelism = 3, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@4163f5af 
2020-03-06 14:10:20,114 [   3993]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Gradle Extension" misses optional descriptor profiler-java-gradle.xml 
2020-03-06 14:10:20,775 [   4654]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (193.6494.35), Android Support (10.3.5), Angular and AngularJS (193.6494.35), Ant (193.6494.35), Application Servers View (193.6494.35), Arquillian (193.6494.35), AspectJ (193.6494.35), Bytecode Viewer (193.6494.35), CFML (193.6494.35), CSS (193.6494.35), ChangeReminder (193.6494.35), Cloud Foundry (193.6494.35), CoffeeScript (193.6494.35), Configuration Script (193.6494.35), Copyright (193.6494.35), Coverage (193.6494.35), Cucumber for Groovy (193.6494.35), Cucumber for Java (193.6494.35), Database Tools and SQL (193.6494.35), Dependency Structure Matrix (193.6494.35), Docker (193.6494.35), Drools (193.6494.35), Eclipse Interoperability (193.6494.35), EditorConfig (193.6494.35), Emma (193.6494.35), FTP/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access) (193.6494.35), Flash/Flex (193.6494.35), FreeMarker (193.6494.35), GWT (193.6494.35), Gherkin (193.6494.35), Git (193.6494.35), GitHub (193.6494.35), GlassFish (193.6494.35), Google App Engine (193.6494.35), Gradle (193.6494.35), Gradle Extension (193.6494.35), Gradle-Java (193.6494.35), Gradle-Maven (193.6494.35), Grails (193.6494.35), Groovy (193.6494.35), Guice (193.6494.35), HTML Tools (193.6494.35), HTTP Client (193.6494.35), Haml (193.6494.35), Helidon (193.6494.35), Hibernate (193.6494.35), IDE Settings Sync (193.6494.35), IDEA CORE (193.6494.35), IntelliLang (193.6494.35), JBoss Frameworks Base (193.6494.35), JBoss Seam (193.6494.35), JBoss Seam Pageflow (193.6494.35), JBoss Seam Pages (193.6494.35), JBoss jBPM (193.6494.35), JSR45 (193.6494.35), JUnit (193.6494.35), Java (193.6494.35), Java Bytecode Decompiler (193.6494.35), Java EE: Batch Applications (193.6494.35), Java EE: Bean Validation (193.6494.35), Java EE: Contexts and Dependency Injection (193.6494.35), Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets (193.6494.35), Java EE: JMS, JSON Processing, Concurrency, Transaction (193.6494.35), Java EE: Java Server Faces (193.6494.35), Java EE: RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) (193.6494.35), Java EE: Web Services (JAX-WS) (193.6494.35), Java EE: WebSockets (193.6494.35), Java HTTP Clients (193.6494.35), Java IDE Customization (193.6494.35), Java Internationalization (193.6494.35), Java Server Pages (JSP) (193.6494.35), Java Stream Debugger (193.6494.35), JavaFX (193.6494.35), JavaScript Debugger (193.6494.35), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (193.6494.35), JavaScript and TypeScript (193.6494.35), Jetty Integration (193.6494.35), Kotlin (1.3.61-release-IJ2019.3-1), Less (193.6494.35), Machine Learning Code Completion (193.6494.35), Markdown (193.6494.35), Maven (193.6494.35), Maven Extension (193.6494.35), Mercurial (193.6494.35), Micronaut (193.6494.35), NodeJS (193.6494.35), OSGi (193.6494.35), Perforce (193.6494.35), Performance Testing (193.6494.35), Persistence Frameworks Support (193.6494.35), Play Framework (193.6494.35), Plugin DevKit (193.6494.35), Properties (193.6494.35), Quarkus (193.6494.35), Reactor (193.6494.35), Refactor-X (193.6494.35), Resin Integration (193.6494.35), SSH Remote Run (193.6494.35), Sass (193.6494.35), Settings Repository (193.6494.35), Shell Script (193.6494.35), Smali Support (193.6494.35), Spring AOP/@AspectJ (193.6494.35), Spring Batch (193.6494.35), Spring Boot (193.6494.35), Spring Data (193.6494.35), Spring Integration Patterns (193.6494.35), Spring MVC (193.6494.35), Spring OSGi (193.6494.35), Spring Security (193.6494.35), Spring Support (193.6494.35), Spring Web Flow (193.6494.35), Spring Web Services (193.6494.35), Spring WebSocket (193.6494.35), Spy-js (193.6494.35), Struts 2 (193.6494.35), Stylus (193.6494.35), Subversion (193.6494.35), Swagger (193.6494.35), Tapestry (193.6494.35), Task Management (193.6494.35), Terminal (193.6494.35), TestNG (193.6494.35), TextMate bundles (193.6494.35), Thymeleaf (193.6494.35), Time Tracking (193.6494.35), Tomcat and TomEE Integration (193.6494.35), UI Designer (193.6494.35), UML (193.6494.35), Velocity (193.6494.35), Virgo/dmServer (193.6494.35), W3C Validators (193.6494.35), WebLogic Integration (193.6494.35), WebSphere Integration (193.6494.35), WildFly (193.6494.35), XPathView + XSLT (193.6494.35), XSLT Debugger (193.6494.35), YAML (193.6494.35), ZKM-Unscramble (193.6494.35), tslint (193.6494.35) 
2020-03-06 14:10:20,775 [   4654]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: ANSI Highlighter (1.2.4), CMD Support (1.0.5), CSV Plugin (2.9.2), Catdea (1.1.4), Ideolog (201.0.19.0), Lombok (0.29-2019.3), Rainbow CSV (1.3) 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,169 [   5048]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === Exit: JBA_NOT_FOUND === 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,363 [   5242]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1994 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,376 [   5255]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - un-interruptible FileChannel-s will be used for indexes 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,491 [   5370]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,734 [   5613]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,908 [   5787]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2020-03-06 14:10:21,956 [   5835]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2020-03-06 14:10:22,089 [   5968]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2020-03-06 14:10:22,177 [   6056]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2020-03-06 14:10:22,247 [   6126]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: VibrantInk from plugin: com.intellij.database 
2020-03-06 14:10:22,247 [   6126]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: WarmNeon from plugin: com.intellij.database 
2020-03-06 14:10:24,322 [   8201]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - touchbar-server isn't running, skip nst loading 
2020-03-06 14:10:24,644 [   8523]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 2661 
2020-03-06 14:10:25,207 [   9086]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 563 
2020-03-06 14:10:30,476 [  14355]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [] 
2020-03-06 14:10:31,063 [  14942]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2020-03-06 14:10:33,489 [  17368]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2020-03-06 14:10:34,045 [  17924]   INFO -              PerformancePlugin - Performance Plugin is in silent mode 
2020-03-06 14:10:35,219 [  19098]   INFO - llij.database.util.SqlDialects - SQL dialects initialized in 15 ms 
2020-03-06 14:10:35,791 [  19670]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2020-03-06 14:10:35,842 [  19721]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 780ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-03-06 14:10:36,481 [  20360]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Registering unknown macros a.b.c in component DatabaseSettings 
2020-03-06 14:10:38,069 [  21948]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 3982ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/4 sluggish, 1/4 very slow 
2020-03-06 14:10:40,171 [  24050]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - /Users/dinicolae/Projects/myProject/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2020-03-06 14:10:40,240 [  24119]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version 
2020-03-06 14:10:40,306 [  24185]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122) 
2020-03-06 14:10:40,323 [  24202]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - Mapped Roots: 1 
2020-03-06 14:10:40,336 [  24215]   INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for /usr/bin/git : 2.21.0 
2020-03-06 14:10:42,274 [  26153]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 12504 ms 
2020-03-06 14:10:49,798 [  33677]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:49,846 [  33725]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:50,207 [  34086]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:50,281 [  34160]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:50,454 [  34333]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:50,456 [  34335]   WARN - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Cannot find class `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.data.AnnotationProcessingData$AnnotationProcessorOutput` 
2020-03-06 14:10:50,648 [  34527]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 2540 millis (read time: 2516) 
2020-03-06 14:10:51,070 [  34949]   INFO - tion.PackageJsonUpdateNotifier - processPackageJsonFiles [] 
2020-03-06 14:10:52,216 [  36095]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 16367ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 2/17 sluggish, 3/17 very slow 
2020-03-06 14:10:52,249 [  36128]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 11 files to update 
2020-03-06 14:10:52,954 [  36833]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 705ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2020-03-06 14:10:54,703 [  38582]   INFO - cloudConfig.CloudConfigManager - === StatusBar ignored === 
2020-03-06 14:12:33,342 [ 137221]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=myProject, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=/Users/dinicolae/Projects/myProject) ArtifactManager took 24 ms, ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration took 12 ms, libraryTable took 19 ms 
2020-03-06 14:12:36,928 [ 140807]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 0 to update, calculated in 2ms 
2020-03-06 14:12:41,105 [ 144984]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=myProject, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=/Users/dinicolae/Projects/myProject) KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 14 ms, RunManager took 32 ms

Comment: Is it an Android project?

Comment: No. Spring boot.

Comment: What IDE do you use - Ultimate or Community edition?

Comment: It is the Ultimate

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE.

Comment: I added the logs

Comment: Could you please check if the issue occurs with new sample Gradle project?

Comment: The picture is from an old version of IntelliJ and they have since changed the way you configure Gradle. If you want to run a test with Gradle, that is now the default behavior of the "run" command. Are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: I was following a guide on how to set up a project and I could not find this option. The project runs fine on my pc, but a colleague has problems running it and we thought this might be the problem.